# Google YouTube API rejecting IP set as accepted

Tags: php, curl, youtube, google-api

I have a PHP-routine that fetches information about a YouTube video through Google's API using curl. The code works like a charm locally, but when run from one specific remote webserver, the API returns an ipRefererBlocked error message indicating that the IP doesn't have access to do the request.

I have of course added the IP address of the server to the list of accepted IP's on the credential section on my Google console, and the system has worked nicely for other IP's, but doesn't for this specific one - which of course is my live server. The access key is OK and I even tried generating a new key for this application only. No go.

The server IP has been checked and is as expected and the code - as already mentioned - works from other servers.

I have run out of ideas about where to look.

Any suggestions to what might be the problem?

Martin

Comment: What happens if you remove everything from "Accept requests from these server IP addresse" and just let all IPs use it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this the minute after posting it.

Google offers to add IP's the old IPv4 form (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn) and IPv6 (nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn or something along that line)

I found my server's IPv6 address, entered that and violá!

Stuff's working now.

Martin